# Enable remote desktop for user created in Active directory

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory

i have created a user in AD DS.
However when i tried to use remote desktop then it says thae Remote desktop is allowed for this user.

Where is the option to make that user use remote desktop

Answer (score 4):

The domain user or group needs to be in the local Remote Desktop Users group on each computer in order to be able to log on to each computer via RDP.

Comment: How to add to local remote desktop user group

Comment: For those of us stumbling upon this post regarding adding users to the local Remote Desktop Users group: http://www.ehow.com/how_6080367_enable-remote-desktop-active-directory.html

Answer (score 0):

There is an AD group for remote desktop users that they need to be added to.

Comment: I added the user to it but when i tried it says that you have to have the terminal services log on enabled either in remote desktop users or in individual user . Where is that option

Comment: The Remote Desktop Users group in Active Directory in the Builtin folder controls remote desktop access to domain controllers only, not member servers.
To allow users to RDP into a member server you have to add their account to the local Remote Desktop Users group on that server.